# Django in-memory database

Tags: django, shared-memory, in-memory-database

I am running a web application with a low latency requirement using Django. However, my MySQL server is currently being a bottleneck. I want to replace it with a completely in-memory database. However, the solutions I have looked at so far create an in-memory database that is local to a particular process. I am running multiple Django processes and need the database to be shared among them. Are there any such databases that can be integrated with Django?

Comment: If it's multiple processes then memory sharing is… difficult. How about Redis or memcached or something like that…?!

Comment: Try to improve the mysql part. You have (usually) a huge potentials in improvements. Check why you have slow queries. Do you have problem in read or write? Could you add  cached results? etc. Try the "simple" part, before to do on complex part

Comment: @deceze Redis looks like a good option. I'll look into it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The web app receives 1000 requests per second, and each request needs a read and a write. Also, the cached results for these queries are not useful. This is why I am considering an in-memory database.

Comment: @deceze There's nothing difficult about an in-memory database in shared memory. eXtremeDB, and probably other in-memory database systems, have offered this for well over a decade.